# How can I access a containing class from its attribute's method in Java

Tags: java, reference

Consider following classes:

```
public class Wizard {}

public interface Castable {
    /**
     * This class returns the owner of the source that is cast
     */
    Wizard getOwner();
}

public class Spell implements Castable{
    Wizard getOwner() {
        // Owner depends on the MagicalStructure this spell sits in
        // no idea what to do here
        // HELP ME THERE
    }

}

public class MagicalStructure implements Castable{
    private Wizard owner;
    private Spell spell;

    getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

}

public class CastableQueue {
    private LinkedList<Castable> queue;

    public Wizard getOwnerOfFirst() {
        return queue.pop().getOwner();
    }
}
```

What is the matter:
I have some interface, lets say `Castable`, with which I am able to do certain action, for which I need to know an owner of implementing class.
I have two different classes implementing this interface, lets say `MagicalStructure` and `Spell`. 
`MagicalStructure` has its owner, some wizard lets say, defined as an attribute `Wizard owner` so getting the owner is easy as I need only one getter for this.
`Spell`, on the other hand, exists only as a part of `MagicalStructure`, so its owner is the same as the owner of the `MagicalStructure` in which the spell sits.

How can I access the owner of `MagicalStructure` from within its `Spell` attribute?
I would also like to access the pointer to the instance of `MagicalStructure` that contains this `Spell` attribute. 
The reason I ask this is because I would like to pre-generate some `Spell` instances and then just add them to the existing `MagicalStructure` instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access `MagicalStructure` from `owner` or from `spell`, unless they have a two-way relationship established.

In order to make such access possible, each `Spell` object must be attached to a particular `MagicalStructure`, for example, at the time it gets attached to `MagicalStructure`:

```
public class Spell implements Castable{
    private MagicalStructure magStruct;
    public setMagicalStruct(MagicalStructure magStruct) {
        this.magStruct = magStruct;
    }
    public Wizard getOwner() {
        return magStruct.owner;
    }
}
```

When you pass `Spell` instance to `MagicalStructure`'s constructor, it calls `setMagicalStruct` on it, like this:

```
public MagicalStructure(Spell spell, Wizard wizard) {
    this.spell = spell;
    this.wizard = wizard;
    this.spell.setMagicalStruct(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I access the owner of `MagicalStructure` from within its `Spell` attribute?

The only way you could do this would be if `Spell` had a field in which you could record a reference to the owner, and from which you could later read that owner back.  More generally, an object knows about the references that are part of its own state, but not about any references *to* it.  You're asking for information related to the latter.

The question is not even well defined in the first place, for there is nothing in any of the classes you presented that could ensure that there is only one `MagicalStructure` that has a reference to a particular `Spell`.  It might work out that way in practice, but the language can't assume it.  In the event that there were more than one, Java could not discern which you wanted.

> I would also like to access the pointer to the instance of `MagicalStructure` that contains this `Spell` attribute.

Supposing that you mean "reference", that's pretty much the same question, with pretty much the same answer.  Objects do not know anything about references *to* them (except self-references) or where such references reside.

You need a different approach.  Instead of your `Spell` class somehow being able to determine for itself the context of methods invoked on it, either record the needed details in its instances, or pass the needed data as method arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have more than one interface hiding in `Castable`. Maybe the interface that provides the owner and the interface that provides, say, effects or costs of casting, are different.

Spell provides the effect or the costs, but can be cast by anybody, so has no owner. How about this:

```
interface Castable {
    CastingResults castBy(Wizard caster)
}
```

Where `CastingResults` would show things like location, duration left, provide effects on the caster (e.g. invisibility) and on other things. And yes, the caster (owner).

Magic structure (such as Ward or Wand) that is locked to an owner would not be a Castable, as it has no need to `caster` argument. It would be some other interface, say

```
interface OwnedArtifact {
    CastingResults use()
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the idea, but I am not able to modify the implementation like this at this point. The magical structure itself must be castable. And really there is no other interface behind Castable.

Comment: OK, another approach then. Add `setOwner(Wizard)` to `Spell`. If `setOwner` was not called yet, `getOwner` throws. In the `MagicStructure` constructor, set the owner of the passed spell.